# Git push to a repository which is 1 commit ahead

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am working on a repository, where lets say I have created a commit 'B'.
Commit 'A' is the origin/master. It looks like this:

```
A -------------------- B
(origin/master)      (HEAD)
```

But someone else pushed a commit (consider it as 'Z') before me, and without knowing that I created another commit on top of B, consider it as 'C'. It looks like this now.

```
      (origin/master)
A --------- Z
 \
  \
   -------- B -------- C
                      (HEAD)
```

How can I first pull the commit 'Z' and then push my local commits. I can confirm (Z) and (B, C) are unrelated file changes. I want them to eventually look like this:

```
A -------- Z -------- B -------- C
                          (HEAD, origin/master)
```

I have tried `git pull --rebase` but no use. Let me know how can I re-enable it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `git pull --rebase` should be working here to arrive at the `A -- Z -- B -- C` branch you want.  You could also try an explicit rebase operation followed by a push:

```
# from local master
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
git push origin master
```